# Ambiguity in Text

Tags: books

John Nunn mentions the following in *Understanding Chess: Move by Move (2002)*:

> Pawn weaknesses vary in severity according to two factors: 1) whether there is any possibility of liquidating the weakness, ...
>
> As an example of the first factor, a backward pawn may not be a real weakness at all if it is impossible to stop the pawn advancing aside another pawn.

How do these two statements tie hand-in-hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally a backward pawn is considered a potential weakness since it cannot be defended by other pawns where it stands, and if it's impossible to move the pawn somehow it can become a very serious weakness indeed. But if the backward pawn can sidestep any threat against it by moving forward it may not even be an issue. In many cases, a backward pawn will come under attack by an enemy pawn if it were to move forward, and this is probably what John Nunn meant in the provided text; the "weak" pawn is pushed forward and will be "liquidated" against the enemy pawn.

Answer (score 6):

The book is right. In chess, nothing is a weakness if it can't be exploited. In the following world championship game, Black had a backward pawn on d6. However, it was not a weakness.

Note b3, Rad8, Red2, d5!, the d5 push will liquidate everything. That was why Carlsen exchanged the pawn with his c4 pawn immediately.

> http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1937912

[image]